# Install Octave package error

Tags: octave

I have tried to install image package but it returned error:

> > pkg install image-2.4.1.tar.gz
> >     pkg: unable to find the command shell.
> >     error: called from 'shell' in file C:\Octave\Octave-4.0.0\share\octave\4.0.0\m\pkg\private\shell.m near line 42, column 7

How can I solve it?

Comment: not sure about the particular error, but does `pkg install image -forge` not work for you?

Comment: http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_Microsoft_Windows

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. "-forge" is an option variable to install package online, which should be no different to local.  By the way, I have already tried it but came with same error.

Answer (score 1):

Octave is trying to execute "sh.exe", but cannot. This exe may come by cygwin or some other tool to allow the execution of Unix style commands.

Comment: it's odd that this would be missing though. the windows installation should have provided everything ...

Comment: It could be just missing entry in %PATH%. Search for the "sh.exe" in Windows, and if you find it, add its path to the PATH environment variable.

Comment: Thanks.  I have searched Windows folder (Win8.1), Program Files and Program Files(x86), but I could not locate sh.exe file.  Would it be any missing on my Window system?